# Adding own logo to the bottom of the cesium application

Tags: cesium, html5, css

I would like to add my own logo at the bottom of the cesium application. I would like to know which file in cesium should use to make this possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var credit = new Cesium.Credit('Title', '../images/facility.gif', 'http://www.cesiumjs.org');

viewer.scene.frameState.creditDisplay.addDefaultCredit(credit)
```

Answer (score 0):

append above cesiumContainer div

```
<div class="creditContainer"></div>
```

Then add on page style tag:

```
<style>
    .creditContainer {
        width: 192px;
        height: 50px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 99999;
        background: url(/logo-white.png) 100% 100% no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        bottom: 120px;
    }
</style>
```